# Getting error while using the random choices function

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pycharm

I'm trying to open random links using

```
webbrowser.open(random.choices("link1","link2","link3")
```

but it's showing error Check it out and help me resolve this issue.

**My code:**

```
webbrowser.open(random.choices("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"))
```

Error I am facing:

```
    total = cum_weights[-1] + 0.0   # convert to float
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: Please show the full trace back

Comment: ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\PYTHON PROGRAMMES\DUSTIN- THE VOICE ASSISTANT\dustin.py", line 233, in <module>
    webbrowser.open(random.choices("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"))
  File "C:\Users\socia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 500, in choices
    total = cum_weights[-1] + 0.0   # convert to float
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
total = cum_weights[-1] + 0.0
```

Try:

```
total = float(cum_weights[-1])
```

**Edit:**

For your other error with `random.choices`, try this instead:

```
webbrowser.open(random.choice(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"]))
```

`random.choices` take in a single argument with a parameter of a list, it isn't a `*args` expression in the implementation.

Comment: This line where the exception is raised is in random.py. It is not editable. The exception is happening because arguments to random.choices() are passed incorrectly.

Comment: **ERROR** ` Traceback (most recent call last):

    webbrowser.open(random.choices(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"]))
  File "C:\Users\socia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 86, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "C:\Users\socia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 603, in open
    os.startfile(url)
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list `

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Edited my answer, should work now, it was as typo

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `random.choices()` must be an iterable like list, tuple, etc like this:

```
random.choices(
("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA")
)
```

Notice the extra pair of parentheses. You can pass as many arguments you want but they should be given like this:

```
random.choices((arg1, arg2, arg3, ...))
```

instead of:

```
random.choices(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)
```

Both of the below options will work:

Use `random.choice()` over `random.choices()` to select only 1 option out of multiple options.

1.

```
webbrowser.open(random.choice(("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA")))
```

2. 

```
webbrowser.open(random.choice(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"]))
```

Comment: @AshutoshSingh edited answer to add code samples, check if it helps you

Comment: no. it's not working :(  ` Traceback (most recent call last)
    webbrowser.open(random.choices(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGf8JJZM_Yg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upsF9NULamA"]))
  File "C:\Users\socia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 86, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "C:\Users\socia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\webbrowser.py", line 603, in open
    os.startfile(url)
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list `

Comment: @AshutoshSingh can you try using random.choice() function instead of random.choices()? It is more suitable when you need only 1 option out of a list of options. Updating my answer accordingly,